# Kubernetes EKS Reschedule Pod Faster After Scaleup

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes cluster that has auto scaling enabled with the default kubernetes autoscaler https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html

When a pod can't find a node to schedule to, the autoscaler scales up and creates a new node. The problem I'm running into is it takes 5 minutes after the scale up event before it tries to schedule the pod onto a node again.

**How can I decrease this time so the pod can be scheduled faster?**

My cluster is using all of the default setup that EKS starts you with.

Comment: You are using `Cluster Autoscaler` or `Karpenter` as your main autoscaling tool?

Comment: I'm using `Cluster Autoscaler`

Comment: What I can advise you is to switch to [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/). When new pod needs to be scheduled `Cluster Autoscaler` is changing amount of instances in `ASG` and schedule pods when new node is visible to cluster. `Karpenter` is bringing up `EC2` instance without `ASG` (which is faster due) and is able to assign pods quicker so before instance will be fully operational on cluster level it can already pull all images. From my experience I was able to reduce autoscaling time from 3 - 5 minutes with `CA` to ~100s with `Karpenter`.

Comment: My only issue with `Karpenter` is I can't find equivalent functionality to `ASG warmpools`. I need to pre-initialize nodes and turn them back on when a scale up event occurs. If you have any ideas on how to do that in `Karpenter` that would be great, otherwise I'm stuck with `Cluster Autoscaler`.

Comment: In current version of `karpenter` I don't think this is possible but you can propose that on project [repo](https://github.com/aws/karpenter). Other options to consider and check are using [AMI](https://karpenter.sh/preview/concepts/node-templates/#specamiselector) (if you can bake some pre-init data to it) or using [snapshots](https://karpenter.sh/preview/concepts/node-templates/#specblockdevicemappings).

Comment: I added a nodeAffinity to the pod, and it schedules right after scale up now. Not sure why that would make the difference. I'll have to verify later if that is actually what made the difference. I also stuck the autoscaler on a seperate nodegroup so I can scale the other group up/down from 0 easier

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by placing the `cluster autoscaler` in a separate node group. I'm not sure why this works, but when it's in a different node group than the one it's autoscaling, the pod is placed on the node immediately after it's ready instead of waiting 5 minutes after the scale up event.

Here is an example of the yaml definition:

```
nodeGroups:
- name: cluster-autoscaler-node
  instanceType: t3.large
  amiFamily: AmazonLinux2
  volumeSize: 50
  desiredCapacity: 1
  minSize: 1
  maxSize: 1
  labels:
    node-type: cluster-autoscaler
  iam:
    withAddonPolicies:
      autoScaler: true
- name: linux-build-servers
  instanceType: t3.medium
  amiFamily: AmazonLinux2
  volumeSize: 300
  desiredCapacity: 0
  minSize: 0
  maxSize: 50
  labels:
    node-type: eks-build-server
```